# Dynamically proxy to subdomain according to path with nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I am attempting to convert all traffic to its "matching" internal equivalent, and proxy the traffic via this new internal URL.

For example,

- http://external.com/image/blue.png will map to http://image.internal.com/blue.png

I have followed the guide [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1095162/nginx-reverse-proxy-path-to-subdomain-and-append-the-rest) to attempt to set this up via nginx, however I am receiving the following error:

`nginx: [emerg] unknown "path" variable`

Below is my nginx configuration file:

```html
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  
  root /var/www/private/$subdomain;
  
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  
  server_name external.com;
  
  location ~ ^/(?<subdomain>[^/]+)/(<path>.*)?$ {
    proxy_pass http://$subdomain.internal.com/$path;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }
}
```

Do I need to define the 'path' variable somewhere else? All help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a question mark. It's `?<path>` not `<path>`